# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar

Tags: java, sonarqube, semaphore, cicd, sonarcloud

Could anyone help me understand this, i've tried investigating into an issue all day but can't seem to see much configuration choices on sonarcloud for it. I see online that sonarqube is being used I believe under the hood as version 8 and see online that I may need to update to 9. Does this seem like my issue or am I just going down a rabbit hole?

```
Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project abovo: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.InputComponentStore: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.scanner.scan.branch.BranchConfiguration: Could not find a default branch to fall back on.
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project abovo: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.InputComponentStore

 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.InputComponentStore
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.InputComponentStore
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (ComponentContainer.java:52)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter (SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments (ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run (ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe (AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance (ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance (AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance (AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance (Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable (DefaultPicoContainer.java:1034)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable (DefaultPicoContainer.java:1026)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters (DefaultPicoContainer.java:1003)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start (DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents (ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute (ComponentContainer.java:109)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart (GlobalContainer.java:130)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents (ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute (ComponentContainer.java:109)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute (Batch.java:58)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute (Batch.java:52)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute (BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke (IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.execute (Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute (EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute (EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:65)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.scanner.scan.branch.BranchConfiguration
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (ComponentContainer.java:52)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter (SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments (ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run (ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe (AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance (ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance (AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance (AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance (Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance (DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (ComponentContainer.java:50)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter (SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments (ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run (ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe (AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance (ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance (AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance (AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance (Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable (DefaultPicoContainer.java:1034)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable (DefaultPicoContainer.java:1026)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters (DefaultPicoContainer.java:1003)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start (DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents (ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute (ComponentContainer.java:109)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart (GlobalContainer.java:130)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents (ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute (ComponentContainer.java:109)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute (Batch.java:58)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute (Batch.java:52)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute (BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke (IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.execute (Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute (EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute (EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:65)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Could not find a default branch to fall back on.
Error:  
Error:  
Error:  For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error:  [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Also I managed to find this as well, that also may be of help

```
[INFO] 03:00:21.073 Load project branches
[DEBUG] 03:00:21.616 GET 404 https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_branches/list?project=abovo| time=542ms
[DEBUG] 03:00:21.617 Could not process project branches - continuing without it
[INFO] 03:00:21.617 Load project branches (done) | time=544ms
[INFO] 03:00:21.620 Check ALM binding of project 'abovo'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the github token that was created by a previous user was rendered invalid on deleting the account access, there are new issues with
ERROR: Cannot generate ucfg for file

But that is another issue in itself. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After generating new security token in SONAR cloud and configuring it in CI/CD pipeline the error was resolved. It means old SONAR token was expired or became invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. Initially, I made the mistake of not including the `env` setup within the `build.yml` workflow, which turned out to be the root cause of the exact error you're facing. I hope my solution can be helpful to others who encounter the same issue. I will include all of the necessary configurations for this setup.

Please note that this solution is specifically tailored for Gradle projects. If you are using Maven, you'll need to adjust the configuration accordingly.

`.github/workflows/build.yml`

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - develop
name: Integrate Gradle project with Sonarqube and GitHub Actions
jobs:
  sonarqube:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'
          cache: gradle
      - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
        run: chmod +x gradlew
      - name: Clean directory
        run: ./gradlew clean
      - name: Build sonar with gradle
        run: ./gradlew sonar
        env:
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

`build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    ...
    ...
    id "org.sonarqube" version "4.0.0.2929"
}

sonar {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", "yourProjectKey"
        property "sonar.organization", "yourOrganization"
        property "sonar.host.url", "https://sonarcloud.io"
    }
}
```

`sonar-project.properties`

```
sonar.projectKey=yourProjectKey
sonar.projectName=My Project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=src
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```